# Vertically align nodes in Graphviz using FDP

Tags: graphviz

Could someone let me know how to vertically align the nodes? Here is my code

```
       subgraph clusterDatabase { 
       label="Databases" style=filled; 
       bgcolor="#D0C0A0";
       node [fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 3.3.3.3";
       node [fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 1.1.1.1";
      node [ fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 2.2.2.2";
```

}

and my output is attached in the image[image]

Comment: There are no edges between your nodes - do you *have* to use fdp for the layout?

Comment: I just wanted to show connection between the cluster boxes but not inside the cluster. hence need to use fdp.

Comment: So you would like to layout the clusters with fdp, but each cluster should be a simple vertical stack of nodes?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Answer (score 0):

With fdp, by adding position coordinates, the following code might proximate what you want:

```
graph dfd {
  node[shape=box]
  subgraph clusterDatabase { 
    label="Databases" style=filled; 
    bgcolor="#D0C0A0";
    node [pos="0.2,0.2!" fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 3.3.3.3";
    node [pos="0.0,0.1!" fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 1.1.1.1";
    node [pos="0.2,0.0!" fillcolor="yellow" style="filled" ]"DB 2.2.2.2";
  }
}
```

[image]

I experimented and found out that the vertical alignment is achieved by specifying the positions such that there is no overlapping of the boxes on either of the dimension. Once there is such overlapping, then the boxes overlapping might be moved to avoid the overlapping, and the alignment would not be realized.

In your case, the box "DB 1.1.1.1" intrudes the space for "DB 2.2.2.2", the  "DB 2.2.2.2" is moved to the right to avoid the overlapping.

I have not figured out a way to let the layout to accept overlapping but keep the alignment. (If an expert knows how to do that, please comment.)

Comment: use `overlay=true` to retain overlapping, see "[overlap attribute](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/overlap/)".